# how to set Mandrill with DKIM and SPF in order to receive the activation link via mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mandrill, hotmail

I am working on a new app (Ruby On Rails) and I have been stocked on Mandrill.
The settings are fine because when I try to register a new user I can see in the terminal the actiovation link and I can go through my registration but I don't receive any mails because I have no idea how to set this:
[image]

I tried to follow all the guides but I didn't get them.
Where should I CHANGE these settings?
Thanks for your help

No Answers ???

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your Domain Provider and add there two txt records which will contain texts from Mandrill.

If you use GoDaddy:

1. go to /domains
2. find needed domain
3. go to DNS set up page
4. Add two records (TXT type, copy texts from mandrill)
5. Go to Mandrill, press Test and now they should become green